# Passing Control Object to base constructor

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a parent class who handles setting up all the control properties for a map, because I need that functionality in multiple forms. Since you can not pass anything besides parameters to your child function to the parent class, I have no idea how to continue. Setting up an extra method where you have to add the control to the parent class feels kind of unclean because I need to check the reference each time I call it.

Maybe you have some ideas how to implement this problem. Thanks!

```
public abstract class MapForm 
    {
        protected MapForm(GMapControl mapControl)
        {
            MapControl = mapControl;
        }
        ...
    }
public class TestForm : MapForm
    {
      public TestForm(string searchValue = String.Empty) : 
             Base(this.mapControl) // cant do that of course
       {}
       ...
     }
```

Comment: Can you clarify "// cant do that of course". Why can't you to that?

Comment: Because, as i stated in my question, this is not possible due to the Base Constructor getting called first.

Comment: I might just use a User Control for this. Thanks

Comment: @StephenByrne At the time that code runs, `this.mapControl` wouldn't be initialized with a value, and would therefore be null.

Comment: @Totti This looks like a candidate for the Factory pattern.

Comment: @Amy @Totti - Factory is only half the solution here though. `this.mapControl` should be a constructor parameter to `TestForm`, i.e you invert the dependency and let some other agent create that dependency for you. Then you know it is non-null before ever dereferenced. You could indeed use a Factory here to construct `TestForm`, or better yet use a DI Library like `SimpleInjector`, etc. But I would also ask you to consider - are you sure that a base class is the answer here? e.g. that base class could easily be a dependency of TestForm, not a parent class. and imo that makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I will take a look into that!